# htaccess rewrite rule to allow local development

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mamp

I'm using a .htaccess file to force all 'example.com' requests to 'www.example.com'

The problem is, now I'd like to develop my website locally on my machine, and I'm using a custom host defined as example.local -- that points to my version of the website on my local MAMP stack.

```
#force non-www to www.example.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

How can i modify this htaccess file to not push my example.local requests to www.example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a second condition to your rewrite rule

```
#force non-www to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.local$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```